# How to package a Springboot project into *.ear file by using maven?

Tags: java, maven

I want to package a simple Springboot project into  `*.ear` instead of an `jar` file. How do I modify the `pom.xml` ?

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    </parent>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Did you try a web search for [`Spring Boot EAR`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Spring+Boot+EAR)?

Comment: Google search results all contain multiple modules, and I want to know if one simple module can be directly exported as an ear file.

Comment: My first question would be: Why would you like to make an ear of it?

Comment: @JiazhuoRen Because generally speaking, a Maven module can only generate one artifact, and JAR, WAR, and EAR files are all artifacts, so you need a module for each. At the very minimum, you need a WAR and an EAR, so you need 2 modules.